# How do I get the current date and current time only respectively in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I came across an interesting situation when using this class:

```python
class Company(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
```

```python
c = Company(date=datetime.datetime.now(), time=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Django decides to use `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` defined within the **formats.py** file.
Which makes sense, because I am passing in a `datetime.now()` to both fields.

I think I could make Django to use `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` respectively, if I passed in only the current date and current time in.

Something like this:

```
c = Company(date=datetime.date.now(), time=datetime.time.now())
```

But this obviously throws an exception as now doesn't exist like that.  Is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

For the date, you can use `datetime.date.today()` or `datetime.datetime.now().date()`.

For the time, you can use `datetime.datetime.now().time()`.

---

However, why have separate fields for these in the first place? Why not use a single `DateTimeField`?

You can always define helper functions on the model that return the `.date()` or `.time()` later if you only want one or the other.

Comment: It works Amber many thanks. :) Can accept in 5 min.  The reason I need it this way is because of internationalization and getting American time and date formats translated to the rest of the worlds. :)

Comment: For timezone support, I think it's still better to use a DateTimeField to always store the UTC datetime and then transpose the date to the current timezone at query time.

Comment: @Kave Yeah, what piouk said. Use a DateTimeField that stores UTC and only translate to the relevant timezone (using something like [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)) when you go to display the time. Not only is this a better way of storage, but you also get timezone handling for free because `pytz` was already written for you.

Answer (score 68):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y%m%d")
20151015
```

For the time

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
showtime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
print showtime
2015-10-15 07:49:18
```

Answer (score 34):

```
import datetime

datetime.date.today()  # Returns 2018-01-15

datetime.datetime.now() # Returns 2018-01-15 09:00
```

Comment: Best answer so far!

Answer (score 13):

A related info, to the question...

In django, use `timezone.now()` for the datetime field, as django supports [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/), it just returns datetime based on the `USE TZ` settings, or simply timezone 'aware' datetime objects

For a reference, I've got `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'` and `USE_TZ = True`,

```py
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

print(timezone.now())  # The UTC time
print(timezone.localtime())  # timezone specified time, 
print(datetime.datetime.now())  # default local time

# output
2020-12-11 09:13:32.430605+00:00
2020-12-11 14:43:32.430605+05:30  # IST is UTC+5:30
2020-12-11 14:43:32.510659
```

refer [timezone settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#time-zone) and [Internationalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/) in django docs for more details.

Answer (score 10):

```
 import datetime
```

**Current Date and time**

```
     print(datetime.datetime.now())
     #2019-09-08 09:12:12.473393
```

**Current date only**

```
     print(datetime.date.today())
     #2019-09-08
```

**Current year only**

```
     print(datetime.date.today().year)
     #2019
```

**Current month only**

```
     print(datetime.date.today().month)
     #9
```

**Current day only**

```
     print(datetime.date.today().day)
     #8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get datetime UTC with milliseconds.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.utcnow().isoformat(sep='T', timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'

2020-10-29T14:46:37.655Z
```